# Dynamically Add Div Table Rows in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, html

Im a VB.NET beginnger, can anyone tell me how I can dynamically add a div table row or how I can loop a section of html? thanks.

Comment: ASP.Net, or some kind of screen scraping? And if asp.net, what point in the page lifecycle are we talking about?  Some more context would really be appreciated.

Comment: At Page Load. I want to create a row of input boxes for each additional customer. I then want to fix an id at the end of each input box ie CustomerFullName1,CustomerDOB1,CustomerFullName2,CustomerDOB2, etc.

Comment: I pass the number of additional customers at the page creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions about what your doing (such as you're using ASP.Net) but you can use the Repeater control to loop a section of HTML.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <div>What you want to loop here</div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But of course you'll have to databind the repeater for it to loop through the items that it's databound to. You could also do an inline loop:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   { %>
           <div>Something repeated here</div>
<% } %>
```

You'll have to put the for loop into VB syntax of course.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I will go for the inline loop, but is there a way to pull in a declared value, declared in the vb code file? ie for i = 0 to TotalPeople

Comment: Just put a property in the code behind of the page and then you can access that property like normal from the inline loop (this.MyProperty)